# How to subtract 1 day from a timestamp in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp

I am trying to subtract 1 day :

```
select updt_dttm - 1 day from hstry where roll="X34" ;
```

**Expected:** If `updt_dttm` is `2020-01-07 04:21:40.982202`, my query should return `2020-01-06 04:21:40.982202`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select (updt_dttm  - INTERVAL 1 DAY) as date from hstry where roll="X34" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DATE_SUB() ?

`DATE_SUB($thedateyouchoose, INTERVAL 1 DAY)`